# transition css doesn't work when content change - react

Tags: css, reactjs

I have wizard component with cards, each card expand and collapse with css transition:

```
transition: max-height 600ms;
```

when the card in 'expand' mode it get:

```
max-height: 1000px;
```

(not the real size just for the animation to work, [see here](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/animating_height/))

when the card in 'collapse' mode it get:

```
max-height: 100px; //doesn't collapse totally 100px stay open
```

each time the user clicks on the next button to step over the cards, the wizard changes its state (which card is 'active') and render all the cards with map(), each card get its view mode and render its child components according to the mode. it means that when the view mode of the card changes from 'expand' to 'collapse' its child components changed (also the auto height). I expect the card will collapse in transition, but actually, it does not work. when the card is expand the animation works, but when it should collapse it doesn't.

any suggestion?

Comment: Did you try animating with ReactTransitionGroup?

Comment: Why should I use it? simple css should work. also, ReactTransitionGroup works when components enter or leave from its tag, but I have this components all the time.

Comment: Because ReactTransitionGroup is written in Javascript instead of CSS and and a callback is provided to be invoked when animations are complete instead of relying on CSS transition events.

Comment: How can I do expand/collapse with ReactTransitionGroup ?